# How to cut base path using regex

Tags: regex, linux, bash

Here is the example

```
SF_Library/example/Platform/Analyses-PLATFORM.part0.xml
SF_Library/example/Platform/Models-PLATFORM.part0.xml
SF_Library/example/Platform/Models-PLATFORM.car
SF_Library/example/Platform/DS-PLATFORM.car
```

I want to grab base path which is following.

```
SF_Library/example/Platform/
```

Anybody know what regex should i use for it?

Comment: From memory: assign i=/your /path/to/file then do ‛echo ${i##*/}‛.

Comment: Why negative vote on question? what is wrong with it?

Comment: Lack of research and lack of showing what you tried, I'd guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regexes ain't for extracting substrings. Why not use the `dirname` command?

```
$ dirname /home/foo/whatever.txt
/home/foo
$
```

If you need it in a variable:

```
DIRECTORY=`basename "SF_Library/example/Platform/DS-PLATFORM.car"`
```

Answer (score 7):

You don't need a regex:

```
#!/bin/bash

fullpath="SF_Library/example/Platform/Analyses-PLATFORM.part0.xml"
# or if you read them then: while read fullpath; do

basename=${fullpath%/*}

# or if you read them then: done < input_file.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use **[dirname](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dirname)** command:

```
dirname SF_Library/example/Platform/DS-PLATFORM.car
```

It'll give you: `SF_Library/example/Platform`

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I'll indulge you.

```
^(.*/).*$
```

Dissection:

```
^     beginning of string
(     start of capture group
  .*  series of any number of any character
  /   a slash
)     end of capture group
.*    series of any number of characters that are not slashes
$     end of string
```

This works because `*` is greedy: it matches as many characters as it can (so it will include all the slashes right up to the last one).

But as the other answers have pointed out, a regex is probably not the best way to do this.